# Why when I try to upload an Image with Windows Phone it uploads a random thing?

Tags: c#, php, upload, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to upload an image from my Windows Store App (Windows Phone 8.1) to hosting (using PHP) but always when I "uploaded" the image, and I check its result the "image" it's a corrupted file. I think it's related to the byte array conversion but I haven't found another way to do it. This is my code:

C# Code:

```
byte[] ConvertBitmapToByteArray()
{
    WriteableBitmap bmp = bitmap;

    using (Stream stream = bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public async Task<string> Upload()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content =
                new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                byte[] data = ConvertBitmapToByteArray();
                content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(data)), "userfile", fileNewImage);

                using (
                   var message =
                       await client.PostAsync("http://xplace.com/uploadtest.php", content))
                {
                    var input = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    return input;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $uploaddir = getcwd();
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . "/" . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo '{"result": "sucessfull"}';
    } else {
       echo '{"result": "-1"}';
    }
?>
```

I wish someone could give me an idea about what I my mistake and how to fix it. Thanks in advance for your worthy knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your `byte[] data` through a [`BitmapEncoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) to convert it into a common image format (e.g. BMP, PNG, JPEG) before uploading. At the moment you are just sending the raw ARGB pixel data with no information about how it should be interpreted.

For example, to encode as a BMP:

```
...
byte[] data = bitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray();

using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    // encoder *outputs* to stream
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);

    // encoder's input is the bitmap's pixel data
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, 
        (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, data);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();

    content.Add(new StreamContent(stream.AsStream()), "userfile", fileNewImage);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer just 2 changes:
byte[] data = ConvertBitmapToByteArray();
content.Add(new StreamContent(stream.AsStream()), "userfile", fileNewImage);
I didn't know about that conversion but I'm really thankful!

Comment: You're welcome, I've edited my answer with corrections. `bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsArray()` should be [`bitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582182(v=vs.110).aspx). I believe it will have the same result as your `ConvertBitmapToByteArray` function.